# Inner flexbox overrules flex-grow on outer flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

[image]

```
// jsx in React.js
<Table>
     <StyledTableBody>
       {tradeInData.map(dataRow => {
         return (
           <FlexTableRow key={dataRow.productId}>
             <StyledTableCell style={{flex : "3 1 auto !important"}}>
               <ProductNameDiv>
                 <p>{dataRow.productName} ({dataRow.quantity})</p>
                 {showDeleteIcon && <DeleteOutline
                   style={{ cursor : "pointer" }}
                 />}
               </ProductNameDiv>
               <SecondaryText>Id: {dataRow.productId}</SecondaryText>
             </StyledTableCell>
             <StyledTableCell style={{flex : "1 1 auto !important"}}
             >{dataRow.price}</StyledTableCell>
           </FlexTableRow>
         )}
       )}
     </StyledTableBody>
   </Table>
```

I want the flexbox on `FlexTableRow` to show the 2 elements below it at a 3:1 size ratio. You can see it's about 9:1 right now.

Looks like the flexbox on `ProductNameDiv` is consuming all the space. I can't set it to `display: inline-block` since it is also a flexbox.

I tried `inline-block` on the `SecondaryText` div and that seemed to overwrite the auto margins anyways.

What is the solution to this that will 1) preserve horizontal centering of text, 2) display the 2 children of `FlexTableRow` at roughly 3:1 horizontally?

```
// styled components
const StyledTableBody = styled(TableBody)`
  * {
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

const FlexTableRow = styled(TableRow)`
  display: flex;

  > * {
    border: 2px solid goldenrod !important;
  }
`;

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)`
  border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, .6);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
`;

const ProductNameDiv = styled.div`
  border: 2px dashed lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const SecondaryText = styled.p`
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px dotted lightcoral;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: -12px auto 0 auto;
`;
```

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem in a [**stack snippet**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), or at least a React demo. Otherwise, we can't really see the problem and end up guessing mostly.

Answer (score 1):

As I was recreating the issue in a Codepen I found that Material UI's table elements caused the issue. I simply replaced them with standard HTML elements and the inner flexbox no longer fought against its own `flex-grow` setting:

```
const ReviewTable = styled.table`
  max-width: 100vw;
`;

const FlexTableRow = styled.tr`
  border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, .6);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StyledTableCell = styled.td`
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const ProductInfoCell = styled(StyledTableCell)`
  flex-grow: 3;
`;

const ProductPriceCell = styled(StyledTableCell)`
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
`;
```